# React router : child routers not working

Tags: react-router

I have tried to define child routs with react router ( below code ) but child route is not working and also it doesn't returning any error message.

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Main} >
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="create" component={UserList} />
        <Route path="user/create" component={CreateUser} />
        <Route path="createGroup" component={CreateGroup} />
        <Route path="groups" component={GroupList} />
        <Route path="premission" component={PremissionList}>
            <Route path="create" component={CreatePremission} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I need to route `premission/create` to the create premission component.

Answer (score 0):

To do multiple types of deep level/ nested routing you need to follow following approach:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Main} >
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="create" component={UserList} />
        <Route path="user/create" component={CreateUser} />
        <Route path="createGroup" component={CreateGroup} />
        <Route path="groups" component={GroupList} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/premission" component={PremissionList}>
        <Route path="create" component={CreatePremission} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```